# Выпадающий список в Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как сделать выпадающий список в Xcode (выбор варианта без возможности внесения своего варианта)?

И чтобы на форме он выглядел как textField, а при нажатии открывался список.

Comment: а список в каком виде? обычно делают, чтобы при нажатии появлялся picker view.

Comment: В iOS не используют типичные выпадающие списки. Для этого используется UIPickerView, который обычно отображается, перекрывая весь остальной контент.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такие нестандартные элементы интерфейса берут с CocoaControls.

Например, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=drop+down

Можешь искать по тегам **drop-down list**. А потом переделывай как желает душа. Надеюсь, помог